# getting custom claims in Access Token for Client Server application in Azure AD?

Tags: azure

We have a client-server application that targets enterprise use cases mostly. We want to test if Azure AD is a valid IDP for our application that now supports authorization code flow but may be developed to support for authorization code with PKCE.

Our requirement is that we need 'preferred_username' and 'groups' as claims in the jwt based access tokens. The client application is a desktop based app (Win & linux) that authenticates users using any IDP speaking authorization code flow.

For POC, I used a trial account from Azure ad with default set of users in azure ad. Created security groups in the Azure Ad portal and added users to those groups. I registered apps as desktop/mobile based platforms and with an arbitrary redirect url. Under Token configuration, I added 'preferred_username' in access token as optional claim and 'groups' as part of both ID and Access Tokens.
I have set following in the application manifest:

```
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
```

But these claims are never listed in the access tokens but only appear in ID token.
Is it possible to get these claims in access tokens, so the resultant access tokens can be used by our application?

Tried: Authorization code flow with PKCE for desktop/mobile app.
Expected claims preferred_username and groups in jwt Access token.

TLDR; Following below article, I am expecting an Access Token for my server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api

In my understanding:

Client App    ---> Client App on Azure (with scope perms to Web Api)

Server App    ---> Web API App on Azure (exposing scope)

[CLient App permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixyu1.png)

Also, I think I am dealing with 2 issues here:

1. Get Custom Claims in Access Token with Authorization code (or Auth code + PKCE)
2. Access Token should be meant for my application ( and not MS Graph)

Comment: Did you specify that the claim should be in access tokens in the API's app registration? How are you acquiring the access token?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a App registration, you have to add

groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",

To your manifest to access the security groups
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims

If you creating a enterprise application you can add Attributes & Claims within the single sign on settings.